# What does low-impedance mean in the CMOS inverter circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, inverter, cmos, vlsi

For the CMOS inverter the text states "once the transients have settled, a path always exists between VDD and the output realizing a high output (“one”), or, alternatively, between VSS and output for a low output (“zero”). This is equivalent to stating that the output node is always a low-impedance node in steady state."

What does the last statement about low impedance mean?

Comment: ... It means that the output is close to one of the rails provided a comparatively large load impedance is present.

Comment: This is in contrast to TTL or RTL or OC logic where the impedance is higher and unsymetrical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mosfets can be used as switches.  In a cmos buffer one of the switches is to Vdd and the other is to Vss.  A switch has two states; open or high impedance; or closed or low impedance.  So when output of the cmos buffer is high, the switch to Vdd is closed.  We can tell that this is low impedance by adding a load and seeing the effect.  At no load the output will be Vdd.  If we add load up to the Ioh specification, the output will stay close to Vdd indicating a low impedance path to Vdd.  Similar for low to Vss.